# How do I run an Oracle stored procedure in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oracle, stored-procedures

I have been given read access to an Oracle database to get data for my own database. The DBA has given me a stored procedure that he assures me is all I need but I have been unable to run it from Ruby as yet.

I have the ruby-oci8 gem and the oracle instant client installed.

Here's what I have managed so far.

```
require 'oci8'
conn = OCI8.new('user','pass','//remoteora1:1521/xxxx')
=> #<OCI8::RWHRUBY>
cursor = conn.parse("call REPOSITORY.GET_PMI_ADT( '722833', 'W', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)")
=> #<OCI8::Cursor:0x56f4d50>
```

And this is where I get stuck. I have this OCI8::Cursor object but I don't know what to do with it. It should be returning me a whole bunch of results (where the null values are in the query) but I get nothing. Running cursor.exec with and without parameters (I'm not sure what parameters I need though) gives me errors.

cursor.exec gives

```
OCIError: ORA-06553: PLS-:
ORA-06553: PLS-:
ORA-06553: PLS-:
ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or typ
ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or type of arguments in call to 'GET_PMI_ADT'
ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or type of arguments in call to 'GET_PMI_ADT'
ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or type of arguments in call to 'GET_PMI_ADT'
ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or type of arguments in call to 'GET_PMI_ADT'
ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or type of arguments in call to 'GET_PMI_ADT'
ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or type of arguments in call to 'GET_PMI_ADT'
ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or type of arguments in call to 'GET_PMI_ADT'
```

etc...

cursor.fetch gives

```
OCIError: ORA-24338: statement handle not executed
```

Does anyone have any ideas here? I'm in well over my head.

An update here for anyone who's still watching. If I change the stored procedure to

```
BEGIN REPOSITORY.GET_PMI_ADT( '722833', 'W', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null); END;
```

I now get the error;

```
OCIERROR: ORA-06550: line 1, column 45:
PLS-00363: expression ' NULL' cannot be used as an assignment target
```

Does this confirm that the stored procedure is incorrect? Is there anything obvious to do to correct it?

Comment: Sorry, I should have included that. Added in above.

Comment: Have you tried executing that exact line of code in Oracle? Seems there is a problem with the stored procedure you're trying to invoke.

Comment: I don't have access to the Oracle DB and I've been assured by the DBA that there couldn't possibly be anything wrong with his stored procedure..... I have my suspicions though.

Comment: I will find a delicate way of putting this to my friendly neighbourhood DBA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help:

http://rubyforge.org/forum/forum.php?thread_id=11295&forum_id=1078

Sample is as below:

msi is in the IN variable status and remaining_credit are the OUT variables

```
cursor = conn.parse ('begin ROAMFLEX.GETMSISDNSTATUS(:msi, :status, :remaining_credit); end;')
cursor.bind_param(':msi', '250979923')
cursor.bind_param(':status', nil, String, 20)
cursor.bind_param(':remaining_credit', nil, String, 50)
cursor.exec()
puts cursor[':status']
puts cursor[':remaining_credit_amount']
```

Comment: Thankyou so much! This example was exactly what I needed to modify my code to make it work. After abandoning this for a year, I am now able to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are receiving

```
   PLS-00363: expression ' NULL' cannot be used as an assignment target
```

means that in the stored procedure, some of the parameters are defined as IN OUT which means they must be variables.  It's quite common to use a parameter to hold a return value indicating whether a procedure passed or failed although it's more common to use a function where you can return a boolean true/false to indicate success.

You need to give the DBA the error message you are getting and ask for a full signature for the procedure you are calling which should tell you which variables you are passing in are IN/OUT ones.  Any that are IN only can be passed a constant or NULL whereas those which are OUT or IN OUT need to be variables and you may need to do something depending on what you get back in those variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
# PL/SQL records or object type parameters should be passed as Hash
# test_full_name is procedure name in oracle
# p_employee holds parameter list 
#employee_id is first param defined in stored procedure

require 'ruby-plsql'

p_employee = { :employee_id => 1, :first_name => 'First', :last_name => 'Last', :hire_date => Time.local(2000,01,31) }
 plsql.test_full_name(p_employee)   #plsql should hold connection object
```