# How do I run an Oracle stored function in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oracle, stored-functions

i was able to run and oracle stored procedure thanks to this question:
[How do I run an Oracle stored procedure in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608289/how-do-i-run-an-oracle-stored-procedure-in-ruby)

Now, i'm trying to do the same but on an oracle stored function.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle function always return some value, so, instead of

```
cursor = conn.parse ('begin ROAMFLEX.GETMSISDNSTATUS(:msi, :status, :remaining_credit);end;')
```

you will use

```
cursor = conn.parse ('begin :res = ROAMFLEX.GETMSISDNSTATUS(:msi, :status, :remaining_credit);end;')
```